# Colour cells in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with different values, but most of tham are NaN (None). I want to colour cells where value is not a None, where is actually value. 
For example: dataxml=

```
    1      2     3      4     5 
a  NaN    23    NaN   NaN    65
b  NaN    NaN    54   NaN   NaN
c   33    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
d  NaN    NaN    24   NaN   NaN
```

This code color whole dataframe:

```
def highlight_cells(value):
    if value != None:
        return 'background-color: yellow'

dataxml.style.applymap(highlight_cells)
```

Comment: Are you generating an HTML or Excel file?

Comment: I have parsed XML file, find the difference between attribute value, then transform into pandas dataframe and now I need highlight that cells  with difference to make it easier to find it in excel, if there is no difference, do nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, `df.style` is only used when exporting the dataframe to HTML.

For Excel, If I may suggest using a library that I wrote, see this example code (Note that this is using strings for the column headers since there is a small issue with using integers as headers):

```
import pandas as pd
from StyleFrame import StyleFrame, Styler

df = pd.DataFrame({'1': [None, None, 33, None],
                   '2': [23, None, None, None],
                   '3': [None, 54, None, 24]})

sf = StyleFrame(df)
style = Styler(bg_color='yellow')
for col_name in df.columns:
    sf.apply_style_by_indexes(sf[~df[col_name].isnull()], cols_to_style=col_name,
                              styler_obj=style)
sf.to_excel('test.xlsx').save()
```

This generates the following Excel:

[image]

Comment: But I have 201 rows and 2105 columns. @DeepSpace

Comment: @jovicbg See my updated answer for a generalized solution. The number of rows doesn't matter.

Comment: Just deleted my row names, there is no that first column in excel

Answer (score 2):

you can do it this way:

```
notnull_color = 'yellow'
df.style.applymap(lambda x: 'background-color: %s' % notnull_color if pd.notnull(x) else '')
```

Comment: This actually work, but I can't save it to excel. It's disapeared after running in new jupyter cell